# Is $clog2 task supported in Verilog HDL?

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

When I used it in a program an error was generated (`$clog2` is not supported). But I see our StackOverflowers using `$clog2` task in their program. Please tell me how to use that.

Comment: To fix your specific issue, you can probably tell your simulator to treat your code as SystemVerilog. I don't know what tool you are using but adding something like `-sv` to the command might do the trick.

Comment: It needs to be clearly distinguished whether $clog2 is used for simulation or for synthesis. I believe it's not support for synthesis neither in ISE/Vivado nor Quartus. Although, simulation in Modelsim (and others) supported without issues

Answer (score 7):

`$clog2` is not supported by Verilog. It is a **SystemVerilog** system task. Moreover, system tasks are **not synthesizable**.

However, you can make a **function/macro** which outputs the log bsae 2 value of a given number. Here are some of the examples of user defined implementation:

Using macro:

```
`define CLOG2(x) \
   (x <= 2) ? 1 : \
   (x <= 4) ? 2 : \
   (x <= 8) ? 3 : \
   (x <= 16) ? 4 : \
   (x <= 32) ? 5 : \
   (x <= 64) ? 6 : \
   ..etc, ..
   (x <= 4294967296) ? 32 : \
   -1

parameter MAX_VALUE = 42;
parameter MAX_WIDTH = `CLOG2(MAX_VALUE);
```

Using `function`:

```
function [31:0] log2;
   input [31:0] value;
   integer i;
   reg [31:0] j;
   begin
      j = value - 1;
      log2 = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < 31; i = i + 1)
        if (j[i]) log2 = i+1;
   end
endfunction

initial
 begin
  $display("10 = %d", log2(10));
 end
```

Both the above examples leads to synthesizable code. The user can extend this code as per the maximum bit width requirement.

So, you can either change the compiler to compile SystemVerilog code or implement the above function to make a user-defined log code.

Comment: Although generally considered a SystemVerilog enhancement, `$clog2` was added to Verilog in IEEE Std 1364-2005

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the clarification. AFAIK, it was not a part of Verilog 1364-2001.

Answer (score 6):

`$clog2`**is** supported by Verilog, but only Verilog-2005 (IEEE Std 1364-2005). Since Verilog-2005 was released at the same time as IEEE's SystemVerilog, it is generally considered a SystemVerilog enhancement. Here are two source documenting `$clog2` as a Verilog-2005 feature:

- Sutherland HDL - [Busting the Myth that SystemVerilog is only for Verification](http://sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2013-SNUG-SV_Synthesizable-SystemVerilog_paper.pdf) § 9.6 *Expression size functions*
- Xilinx - [Verilog $clog2 function implemented improperly](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/44586.html)

The Verilog-2005 was mostly an intermediate release for eventual merger of Verilog and SystemVerilog (which happened in IEEE Std 1800-2009). Some simulators may have not implanted Verilog-2005 as everything in it is included in SystemVerilog. If your simulator does not run Verilog-2005 by default, then refer to your manual which may included a option to enable it. Enabling SystemVerilog is another option, or user methods as described in sharvil111's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out that $clog2 is a synthesizable construct and can be handled by most tools. It does not become unsynthesizable simply because it is a system task.

For example, the following is a synthesizable statement:

`logic [$clog2(WIDTH) - 1 : 0] addr;`